# Why is wrong this inline if?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, iif, cls

If have the following statement:

```
return this.revision.HasValue ? this.revision : throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

I thought it would compile as the throw is breaking the normal flow and it shouldn't be a problem to not return a value but it does not build.

Is there a way to put right this statement or why is this not allowed?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** this.revision is int? and the method returns int.

**EDIT 2:** if I have this method

```
public int Test()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The compiler does not complain about not returning a value, I expected the same thing from an inline if ... at least we know that can be done as it's already done in methods.

Comment: What is the return type of your method?

Comment: From msdn: Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: provide your (visual studio) error message. at first sight, revision != exception.

Comment: Added the requested info,thanks.

Comment: `throw` is not a type and a conditional operator is not an `if-else`.

Comment: I think the comment of Tim Schmelter gives the hint. ?: is a conditional operator, and no if statement: ?: operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx - if statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I can't believe that people are wasting so much time with this question. This is simply a syntax error.

Comment: @KaiHartmann: thanks for pointing out where muy fault was. If you wrrite it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 13):

Converting comment to an answer:

From MSDN:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

[?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As `int?` cannot be converted to an exception, and throw is not an expression, hence the error within your code.

Comment: Again, I expected the compiler to be smart enough to realize that in this case the return value does not matter ... Check my edit

Comment: but it's slightly different than a traditional if..else statement in that it the types have to match or be able to be converted for assignment.

Comment: "I expected the computer to violate it's programming and read my mind. Please help, internet."

Comment: @SoMoS: The compiler is smart but it has to follow rules and one rule is that the syntax must be valid. If you use a conditional operator the rules are strict. If you don't like it you have to use an `if-else`.

Comment: @Ric: _"int? cannot be converted to an exception, hence the error within your code"_ Even if it could be converted to an exception the code would be invalid since `throw` is not an exception type, `throw` is disallowed in a conditional operator.

Comment: _As int? cannot be converted to an exception_ -> wrong, it's not the cause at all. If the OP used an exception instead, it wouldn't work either.

Comment: @ken2k Just pointing out the type mistmatch is all I was getting at. How would you have worded it? Also the quote from MSDN clearly illustrates that types must be the same or a conversion must exist.

Comment: @Ric: A conditional operator needs two [**expressions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144(v=vs.110).aspx) and each expression must have the same type (or an implicit conversion exists). `throw` is a [**statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143(v=vs.110).aspx) not an expression.

Comment: @Ric That's not a type mismatch, it's just `throw` is not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the problem is in the fact that this.revision is a nullable type and InvalidOperationException() is a SystemException. You cannot have two different types in an if statement like:

```
return (a>b)? DateTime.Now : 2;
```

Please look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx

condition ? first_expression : second_expression;

The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true, first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one of the two expressions is evaluated.

Either the type of first_expression and second_expression **must be the same**, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Comment: I expected the compiler to be smart enough to realize that in this case the return value does not matter ...

Comment: @SoMoS the ternary operator requires the types to be the same or implicitly convertible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's because in a [ternary expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the latter two expressions act as a substitute to each other and their return value needs to be of same type or implicitly convertible to type of the variable being assigned.
Clearly, an `Exception` has different type than an `int`.

**MSDN:**

> If condition is false, **second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result**.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the second operand of `?:` needs to be an expression, not a throw statement.

so what you can do is-

```
public static T ThrowException<T>()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

and use it in your statement

```
return this.revision.HasValue ? this.revision :ThrowException<bool>();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler could allow for that and it could do many more things than it does today. The problem is the cost of writing the feature and then supporting it. See [Eric Gunnerson's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) outlining the new feature decision process.